# Another neural network knight's tour conundrum

Tags: java, graph, neural-network, knights-tour

I've done my best to make a simple java implementation of the neural network knight's tour finder but I'm completely stumped as to why it fails to work..

there are 6 classes, 3 for the GUI which im pretty sure works fine, and 3 to deal with the actual logic etc.

If you are wondering, this is inspired by  [Yacoby's python offering](http://www.yacoby.net/programming/knights-tour.html)  He had a problem with the implementation also, although I don't think I'm making the same mistake..

I appreciate its not super coding, but any suggestions gratefully received

Neuron class:

```
package model;

import java.util.Random;

public class Neuron {


boolean oldActive=true,active=true; //ie part of the solution
int state=0,previousState=0;

public Square s1,s2;

public Neuron(Square s1,Square s2){
    this.s1=s1;this.s2=s2;


    //status of the neuron is initialised randomly
    oldActive=active= (new Random()).nextInt(2)==1?true:false;

}

public int activeNeighbours(){

    //discount this neuron if it is active
    int s=0;if(isActive()){s=-2;}

    for(Object o:s1.neurons)
        if(((Neuron)o).isActive())s++;

    for(Object o:s2.neurons)
        if(((Neuron)o).isActive())s++;


    return s;

}

public boolean hasChanged(){
    return  oldActive != active||previousState != state;
}



public boolean isActive(){return active;}

public void updateState(){
    previousState=state;
    state+=2-activeNeighbours();
}

public void updateOutput(){
    oldActive=active;
    if (state>3) active=true;
    else if(state<0)active=false;

}


}
```

Square class:

```
package model;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Square {

Vector neurons=new Vector();//neurons which connect to this square
public int col;
public int row;

public Square(int row, int col){

    this.col=col;
    this.row=row;


}


/**
 * creates a neuron which links this square with the square s,
 * then tells both squares about it,
 * also returns the neuron for inclusion in the global list.
 * 
 * @param s
 * @return neuron n, or null
 */
public Neuron link(Square s){

    for(Object o: neurons)
        //discounts the link if it has already been created
        if (((Neuron)o).s1==s ||((Neuron)o).s2==s)return null;

    Neuron n=new Neuron(this,s);
    neurons.add(n);
    s.neurons.add(n);
    return n;

}


}
```

Control class:

```
package model;

import java.util.Vector;
import gui.Board;

public class Control {
Board b; //the graphic board

Vector neurons=new Vector();   //all 168 neurons

Square[][] squares=new Square[8][8];

int[][] moves={
        {-2,-2, 2, 2,-1,-1, 1, 1},
        { 1,-1, 1,-1, 2,-2, 2,-2}};

public Control(Board b){
    this.b=b;

    //create 64 squares
    for(int row=0;row<8;row++)
        for (int col=0;col<8;col++)
            squares[row][col]=new Square(row,col);

    //create neurons
    for(int row=0;row<8;row++)
        for(int col=0;col<8;col++)
            findMoves(squares[row][col]);

    dl();//draw the initial active neurons on the graphic

    //try this many enumerations of the board before giving up
    int counter=1000;

    //the main updating loop
    while(counter>0){
        for(Object o:neurons)((Neuron)o).updateState();//update all the states
        for(Object o:neurons)((Neuron)o).updateOutput();//then all the outputs

        counter--;

        if(isStable())break;
    }

    dl();   //draw the neurons when the solution is found/attempt abandoned
}

/**
 * draws the lines (active neurons) on the graphic display
 */
private void dl(){
    b.clear();
    for(Object o:neurons)
        b.drawLine((Neuron)o);
    b.repaint();


}


/**
 * Identify all of the squares legal to move to from this one - link with a neuron,
 * then add the neuron to the collection
 * 
 * @param s
 */
private void findMoves(Square s){

    for (int i=0;i<moves[0].length;i++){
        int newRow=s.row+moves[0][i];
        int newCol=s.col+moves[1][i];

        if(isInBounds(newRow,newCol)){

            Neuron n=s.link(squares[newRow][newCol]);
            if (n!=null)neurons.add(n);         
        }           
    }

}

/**
 * tests whether the identified square is contained within the (8*8) board
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return
 */
private boolean isInBounds(int row,int col){
    if (row>=0 && row<8 && col>=0 && col<8)return true;
    return false;
}


/**
 * returns true if no neuron changes its state/output
 * @return
 */
private boolean isStable(){

    for (Object o:neurons)
        if(((Neuron)o).hasChanged())
            return false;
    return true;

}



public static void main(String[]s){
    Board b=new Board(50,50,60);
    new Control(b);
}

}
```

the GUI classes: -

Board class:

```
package gui;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import model.Neuron;
/**
* sets up the graphic representation of the chess board, and draws on the neurons as required
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param squareSize
 */
public class Board extends JFrame {
Vector lines=new Vector();
int squareSize;

public Board(int x, int y,int squareSize){

    //initialize dimensions etc
    super("there.");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setBounds(x,y,squareSize*8+8,squareSize*8+30);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.squareSize=squareSize;

    //draw the squares
    drawSquares();

    repaint();
}

private void drawSquares(){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
            GuiSquare s=new GuiSquare(i,j,squareSize);
            this.add(s,0);
        }
}

/**
 * represent the neuron as a line on the board
 * @param n
 */
public void drawLine(Neuron n){
    Line l=new Line(n.s1.col+n.s1.row*8,n.s2.col+n.s2.row*8,squareSize);
    if(n.isActive()){
        lines.add(l);
        add (l,0);
    }
}

/**
 * removes all of the lines (neurons) from the board
 */
public void clear(){
    for(Object o:lines)
        remove((Line)o);

    lines.clear();
}
```

}

GuiSquare class:

```
package gui;
import java.awt.*;

public class GuiSquare extends Component{

int row,col;
int x;
int y;
int size;

public GuiSquare(int row,int col,int size){

    this.row=row;this.col=col;this.size=size;
    y=row*size; x=col*size;
    setBounds(x,y,size,size);
    setBackground((row+col)%2==0?Color.white:Color.black);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(getBackground());        
    g.fillRect(0,0, size-1, size-1);
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.drawString(""+((row*8)+col), size/2, size/2);
}
}
```

Line class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.*;

public class Line extends Component{

int x1,y1,x2,y2;
int x,y,w,h;

public Line(int a,int b, int squareSize){
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    x1=((a%8)*squareSize)+(squareSize/2);
    y1=((a/8)*squareSize)+(squareSize/2);
    x2=((b%8)*squareSize)+(squareSize/2);
    y2=((b/8)*squareSize)+(squareSize/2);

    if(x1<x2){
        x=x1;w=x2-x1;
    }else{
        x=x2;w=x1-x2;
    }

    if(y1<y2){
        y=y1;h=y2-y1;
    }else{
        y=y2;h=y1-y2;
    }
    setBounds(x,y,w,h);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.drawLine(x1-x,y1-y,x2-x,y2-y);
}

}
```

Comment: not sure we really respond well to the whole "hey i have this mountain of code debug it for me" problem here...

Comment: It would be best if you described what exactly is failing.  Does it crash, does it make your computer blue screen, does it evolve into skynet?

Comment: @temp2290 ... well to be fair, it's a lot better than "here's my homework send me the codez plz"

Comment: +1 does it evolve into skynet?

Comment: -1.  Sorry guys.  Doesn't evolve satisfactorily at all really.  It should converge on a solution of some kind within 100 iterations or so, but although it look like its on the way, it fails to complete the tour.

I guess the question is really do you think that the processing (in the neuron class) does the job as described in the Knight's tour wikipedia article? As otherwise I can't figure out why it fails to converge on a solution.

Comment: and to temp2290 -  sorry you feel that way.  I've never posted on one of these things before, I only included all the code so with a bit of cut and paste you could have a go on it yourself if you were so inclined!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with my code, in that it works fine, but it seems to use a slightly different equation than the one proposed on Wikipedia due to it taking into account the active status of the current neurons. It is waiting for me to go back to it and write it so it uses the proposed formula

Try:

```
public int activeNeighbours(){
    int s=0; //changed
    for(Object o:s1.neurons)
            if(((Neuron)o).isActive())s++;
    for(Object o:s2.neurons)
            if(((Neuron)o).isActive())s++;
    return s;
}

public boolean hasChanged(){
    return  oldActive != active||previousState != state;
}



public boolean isActive(){return active;}

public void updateState(){
    previousState=state;
    state+=4-activeNeighbours(); //changed
}
```

Comment: hmm cheers for replying!  I tried changing these, and had broadly the same problem as before, 

In your python code, you set s to be -2, even if the current neuron is not active.  In this case, the sum of the active adjecent neurons could theoretically be a negative number, surely? Is this condition possible/desirable/a problem?